# How to evaluate anti-virus solutions

Tags: antivirus

Some people want to know what is the "best antivirus", I am a little disappointed and it's difficult for me to answer this question. I think Windows Defender is good but I can't give arguments. How can I answer this?

Comment: If you search for AV rating sites, they will provide their own ways of evaluating and comparing AV software.

Comment: I don't know who *"Some People"* are, but I suggest you respond with addressing the infrastructure and asking, "Who will maintain whatever AV is chosen, and at what cost?" It's not just a question of "Best".

Comment: For the average person, Windows Defender is probably what you want. It's fast and designed quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when doing a product evaluation you look at multiple factors:

- What do you seek as minimum features to achieve the desired outcome (e.g. centrally managed, easy deployment, offline/online updates, HIDS/HIPS support, file integrity monitoring, etc...)
- For AV specifically you want to look at coverage, this can be seen in most comparison websites (e.g. after submitting x amount of samples, how many were detected)
- How fast do they update their sources
- What's the cost

This is what I would normally put as part of an evaluation for AV.